# Colour only one part of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, css

How would I go about coloring only one part of an HTML element with something like `background-clip` - using CSS only.

**I'm looking something like:**

```
div {
   background-image: url('mi_image');
   ***: 50% 30em; /* Background only covering 50% height and 30em width */
}
```

I'm also open to a JavaScript solution, if necessary - but pure CSS would be better.

Comment: Is `mi_image` a solid colored image or does it have a pattern of some sort?

Comment: Is a square that is repeated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a background div. Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="outer-container">
    <div id="container-background"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <p>
            Here's some of my interesting text        
        </p>    
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer-container {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #container-background {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: #FF0000; /* Use background-image or whatever suits you here */
        width: 50%; /* Your width */
        height: 200px; /* Your height */
        z-index: -1;
    }​
</style>
```

To create a result like this:

[image: demo]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xP8H/1/)

Comment: I would have to make it by javascript because I need to part color several elements, I think I am going to set width and height of the filler element setting the style property.

Comment: @juanpastas I'm not sure I understand - this will work for an infinite number of elements. If you want several backgrounds, check out my updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xP8H/2/

Comment: I see. Is in separate elements, I mean not several fillers in one container, instead one filler per container, but I get the idea. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can color *part of the element's background* using the pseudo `:before` element.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/yw3wF/

**Code:**

```
<div class="foo">This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. This is the element. </div>

.foo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.foo:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely sure that I understand your question, but check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJSdq/ and see if that is what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    This is my div and I love my divs. I take good care of my divs; they are my babies.
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:yellow;
    background-clip:content-box;
    -webkit-background-clip:content-box;
    border:2px solid black;
} ​
```

However if you want to color only a part of a div non-symmetrically, then your best bet is to use sub divs and color that div instead. This method is preferred because it will have better browser support than newer CSS3 techniques that I am not aware of. For the latter example, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aD9mF/.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    This is my first div.
    <div>
        This is my sub-div.        
    </div>
<div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
div div{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    border:none
}
```